# Gem rb-inotify causing libffi errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, guard

I'm trying to use guard on my system. With the [Gemfile](http://pastebin.com/nQPympJA) as is, I'm only using

```
gem 'libnotify', '0.5.9'`
gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
```

When I run guard `bundle exec guard`, I get this [error](http://pastebin.com/2bJxZ43P):

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/lib/ffi.rb:11:in
`require': ffi_prep_cif failed.  status=0x2 (fatal)
```

I can however still run my tests via `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`.  Now if I use the gem `gem 'rb-inotify', '0.8.8'` as I'm supposed to according to [this Ruby on Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages?version=3.2#sec%3aguard), and try to run my tests, they fail with the same error as above (ffi_prep_cif failed).

When I do an `ls` on `/usr/local/lib`, I see a few `libffi` files. Could this be a problem? Can anyone explain what's going on here & why `rb-inotify` is acting up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of libffi are you using?  The libffi github repo had a ffi_prep_cif bug these past few days that would have resulted in the failure you're seeing.  It was fixed last night.